# Making sense of memory gibberish (C)

Tags: c, memory

Right of the bat, this question doesn't have a practical purpose, it's just for understanding memory better.
Consider the following code:

```
char some[];
for(int i = 0; ; i++) {
        printf("%c", some[i]);
}
```

The first 9 chars are the same, since the string hasn't been initialized it prints out garbage. Now after the end of the string the program doesn't stop, it keeps printing `char`-s even though those bytes don't belong to the program and the OS should kill the program on the 11th iteration of the loop.

But that never happens, after the string is printed it keeps going. Almost every time the length is different from a few cmd rows to sometimes around a megabyte of text. So, first question,

**1. Why every time the program is run it takes the OS a random amount of time to kill the program after accessing the 11th byte? And how come it never does it on the 11th?**

Some of the output is complete and utter gibberish like this:

```
E  €E  !0  30  mE  Q   Е2  Е2  Ы0  Ы0          ч<           * * Ґ  “E  ЈE  ^  [1  #  #  Ґ  {  Ѓ  Ґ  ґ  с3  4  Ґ    ґE  Ј1  <4    w/  z/  U4        СE  zz            8    Љ  Љ  Ќ  Ќ  ђ  T$  Ќ  ђ      ™          Г  E9  ЯE  =F  UF  E9  zдR'<O.  -  YF    ^F  ^F  jF  jF  qF  vF  zF  F  ЌF  “F    qF    уF  /G  yG  yG          ­G              * * Ґ  ±G  ±G  ^  ЕG  ЛG  ХG  Ґ  аG  аG  Ґ    э9  ыG  Ґ    H  к  H  .          ;H      $  ?H  MM          [    EH  EH  Ќ  ђ  Ќ  IH  ђ  Ќ      ™  LH  TH  yH  ©H  ±H  ЙH  бH  зH  Mйэйэйэфq    -  нH     тH  ьH  I  I  I  I  I  I  -I  2I  DI  I     ‹I  ЙI  =J  ЃJ          ЇJ             * * Ґ  іJ  ЕJ  ^  a  #  #  Ґ  ФJ  ФJ  Ґ  ґ  хJ  K  Ґ  $  'K  DK  KK  q          YK  cK  0  ЃK   Ђ           я    Љ  Љ  3   ђ  Ќ  ‡K  ђ  Ќ      ™  ЊK  —K  Г  г  -  µK  Ґ$  Ї    йэйэйэфп   -  ё   +  »K  АK  ИK  ТK  ЬK  бK  еK  кK  юK  э   +  ЬK  +  YL  ЌL  щL  %M          щ#           * * Ґ  AM  QM  ^  a  #  #  Ґ  dM  dM  Ґ  [  П&  ЌL  Ґ  0  Ы  к  Х,  п          г,      =  hM   Ђ         "    Љ  Љ  3   Ќ  ђ  nM  Ќ  ђ      ™  њ     Г  г  qM  ЎM  ·M  Ї    йэйэйэфЩ   -  ё   8  »M  ЕM  РM  ЧM  ЯM  дM  иM  нM  уM  э   8  ЯM  8  7N  kN  ЭN  !O  їO  P  GP           * * Ґ  wP  ‰P  ^  ќP  #  #  Ґ  аG  аG  Ґ  [  П&  µP  Ґ  =  ЕP  к  KK  Щ          №1      N  ФP  ,,          в   Љ  Љ  3   Ќ  Q$  ЪP  Ќ  Q$      ™          Г  г  ыP  Q  Ґ$  E9  ,гb'ђQ   8
Q  Q  "  Q  .Q  ?Q  KQ  WQ  \Q  `Q  eQ  xQ  ‹Q  ќQ  WQ  E  нQ  R  R  ЩR  эR  S  US            * * Ґ  cS  ‡S  ^  a  #  #  Ґ   S  «S  Ґ  N  э9  R  Ґ  N  ±S  ЬS  KK     гS  жS  сS  щS  c  ФP  ,,           в   Љ  Љ  3   Ќ  ђ  ЪP  Ќ  ђ      ™  њ     Г  г  T  /T  Ґ$  Ї   ,жYa'©Q   7
Q  WQ  "  5T  JT  ?Q  VT  WQ  \Q  `Q  eQ  bT  uT  ќQ  WQ  Z  СT  U  gU  µU  %V      cV            * * Ґ  “V  ґV  ^  a  #  #  Ґ  НV  НV  Ґ  c  П&  U  Ґ  c  УV  к  юV
```

Also, some of the `char`-s are blank squares. If I'm not mistaken that means that the program couldn't recognize the symbol.

**2. How is that possible given the ASCII table has 255 symbols and a C `char` is 1 byte long? Why isn't it displaying the characters from the extended set?**

However, other parts consist of valid words:

```
C o s t a   R i c a    C R I    C R    C R C    C o s t a   R i c a n   C o l у n    c o l у n   c o s t a r r i c e n s e    S p a n i s h   ( C o s t a   R i c a )    e s p a с o l   ( C o s t a   R i c a )   
 1 4 0 a : 0 0 0 0 0 8 0 a    E S K    C u b a    C U B    C U    C U P   
 C u b a n   P e s o    p e s o   c u b a n o    S p a n i s h   ( C u b a )    e s p a с o l   ( C u b a )   
 0 8 0 a : 0 0 0 0 0 8 0 a    E S D    D o m i n i c a n   R e p u b l i c    R e p ъ b l i c a   D o m i n i c a n a    D O M    D O P    D o m i n i c a n   P e s o    p e s o   d o m i n i c a n o    S p a n i s h   ( D o m i n i c a n   R e p u b l i c )    e s p a с o l   ( R e p ъ b l i c a   D o m i n i c a n a )   
 1 c 0 a : 0 0 0 0 0 8 0 a    E S F    E c u a d o r    E C U    E C    d у l a r   e s t a d o u n i d e n s e    S p a n i s h   ( E c u a d o r )    e s p a с o l   ( E c u a d o r )   
 3 0 0 a : 0 0 0 0 0 8 0 a   
 H H ' H ' m m . s s      Х1  Щ  цj  мj  ¦а     [   з1  [Ѕ  ЧE  #k  K6  йP  у     d d d d ,   d '   d e   ' M M M M '   d e   ' y y y y      Са   F  %F     H H ' H ' m m ' ' ' ' s s ' ' ' ' ' '      Х1  Щ  …  ча     E S N    d o .    l u .    m a .    m i .    j u .    v i .    s б .    б  !б  &б  +б  0б  5б  :б    # S p a n i s h   ( S p a i n ,   I n t e r n a t i o n a l   S o r t )   . e s p a с o l   ( E s p a с a ,   a l f a b e t i z a c i у n   i n t e r n a c i o n a l )    H H ' H ' m m    –  …  l  l  ¤б     L    X    J    V    РЕ  №б  -Н  јб  їб  Вб  оB    
 0 c 0 a : 0 0 0 0 0 4 0 a   ) k 0 - w i n d o w s - s p a n i s h ; k 0 - w i n d o w s - s p a n i s h - v a r    d d . M M M . y y y y      [   з1  [Ѕ  ЧE  K6  йP  у  в     l u n    j u e    GN  /в  QN  VN  4в  `N  eN     e n e    o c t    d i c     
 Iв  аO  QN  еO  кO  К  П  щO  Щ  Nв  Ю  Sв        ! S p a n i s h   ( S p a i n ,   T r a d i t i o n a l   S o r t )   , e s p a с o l   ( E s p a с a ,   a l f a b e t i z a c i у n   t r a d i c i o n a l )    H H ' H ' m m ' ' ' '    –  …  Жв     E q u a t o r i a l   G u i n e a    G u i n e a   E c u a t o r i a l    G N Q    G Q    f r a n c o   C F A   d e   Б f r i c a   C e n t r a l    S p a n i s h   ( E q u a t o r i a l   G u i n e a )    e s p a с o l   ( G u i n e a   E c u a t o r i a l )    Q    E S G       G u a t e m a l a    G T M    G T    G T Q    G u a t e m a l a n   Q u e t z a l    q u e t z a l    S p a n i s h   ( G u a t e m a l a )    e s p a с o l   ( G u a t e m a l a )   
 1 0 0 a : 0 0 0 0 0 8 0 a    d d d d   d d   ' d e '   M M M M   ' d e '   y y y y    d d   ' d e '   M M M M   ' d e '   y y y y      Щг  цг     E S H    H o n d u r a s    H N D    H N    H N L    H o n d u r a n   L e m p i r a    l e m p i r a   h o n d u r e с o    S p a n i s h   ( H o n d u r a s )    e s p a с o l   ( H o n d u r a s )   
 4 8 0 a : 0 0 0 0 0 8 0 a      И1  I   Х1  Щ     [   6ј  з1  [Ѕ  ЧE  K6  у     Са  %F     32  Ґ   Х1  Щ     E S M    M e x i c o    M й x i c o
```

Also, there was one time when I landed on some with HTML-like tags `<> </>`. The only word I could make out was "assembly".

**3. Is it correct to assume that the bytes in question are being used by some other program?**

If it matters, the IDE is Visual Studio Community 2017 for Windows 10.

Comment: That code you provided is not valid C

Comment: @machine_1 What invalidates it?

Comment: "What invalidates it?" It depends. If that's the only declaration of `some` then no array dimension has been specified, so its type is incomplete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, the code won't compile as is because you can't define an array without a size.

Assuming you did fix the array:

```
char some[10];
```

Reading past the 10th element of the array invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  This does not guarantee a crash.  it just means you can't predict the behavior of the program.  It could crash, it could output strange results, or it could appear to work properly.  Just because it can crash doesn't mean it will.

Regarding not printing extended ASCII characters, how characters are printed is dependent on your terminal.  It might print extended ASCII or it might attempt to interpret the bytes as UTF8 and display them accordingly.

When the OS gives memory to a process, that memory is typically zeroed out first before the process gets it, so any values you see came from your process.  Some of it could be environment variables that the process knows about, so that could explain some of the text you saw, however you can't depend on seeing anything specific because you've invoked undefined behavior.

Comment: `When the OS gives memory to a process, that memory is typically zeroed out first before the process gets it` - are you sure about this? In my experience uninitialized variables (stack and heap) get whatever was already in memory and that's more often than not non-zero

Comment: @GovindParmar Yes, otherwise you have a security hole where one process could read values owned by another, possibly privileged, process.  Any other possible values have to originate from the current process.

Comment: @GovindParmar It may be uninitialized locally (at the time it is used), but the underlying memory page would have started off zeroed (or filled with 0xdeadbeef or whatever) at the time it was first accessed by the process. That is necessary for security reasons.

Comment: @Govind When an OS maps physical pages to a process’ virtual memory it provides zeroed pages. If it didn’t you could see data from an old process and that would be a security risk. By the time *this* process looks at it, though, it has loaded code and stack data so it is no longer zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Why every time the program is run it takes the OS a random amount of time to kill the program after accessing the 11th byte? And how come it never does it on the 11th?

You are invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by accessing an array beyond its boundaries. Anything can happen.

> 3. Is it correct to assume that the bytes in question are being used by some other program?

No, because on modern operating systems a process running in user mode will see its own [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).  What you're seeing is the encoding of bytes from your own process' memory as whatever character set your terminal is using.

Comment: "No, because on modern operating systems a process running in user mode will see its own virtual address space." If that's the case then how did those valid words get in there? What set the individual bytes to spell out valid names?

Comment: @VictorSysoev You probably have those somewhere in your program. If you provide a *Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example*  (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you might get a sensible answer.

Comment: @Victor Your process executable and DLLs are loaded into its virtual address space. Some of that content is from those binaries.

Comment: @Victor Some of the gibberish looks like Windows timezone information (EDIT: actually, more like locale information), presumably loaded by some C runtime DLL.

Comment: @VictorSysoev Yes, since the code you provided is invalid, as  machine_1 said, and, even if it was, produces undefined behavior.